# Why isn't styled-component applied normally?

Tags: reactjs, styled-components

https://github.com/Miral3/kalba/blob/main/src/components/Table/Table.js
In line 139, pass editMode as props

https://github.com/Miral3/kalba/blob/main/src/components/Table/StandardList.js
I wrote a code that receives props from line 156->132->37->48 and changes the color according to the editMode state

However, editMode keeps changing to true and false, but will the color change from blue -> red only at the beginning and remain red after that?

Comment: Who do you think will open your GitHub link to open that file, view the code of colour change and edit? If you post the relevant code how you are trying to change the colour then someone could help...

Comment: Minimized to the following: https://codesandbox.io/s/styled-inside-hover-h3pec?file=/src/App.js Please check if this is really the same issue.